# loop of zips in python

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, zip

I want to create a loop of zips I have `sample.csv` file with the below entries:

```
> 1      2       3     4
> a      b       c     d
> apple  banana  cat   dog
```

and have the below code:

```
sample= open("sample.csv)
lines = sample.readlines()
testcol = []
for l in lines:
     zipped = zip(testcol ,l)
```

The output is:

```
[(('1','a'),'apple'),(('2','b'),'banana'),(('3','c'),'cat'),(('4','d'),'dog')]
```

but what i want is:

```
    [('1','a','apple'),('2','b','banana'),('3','c','cat'),('4','d','dog')]
```

The reason why i have to put it in loops is because my `sample.csv` may contain arbitrary number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
sample = open("sample.csv)
lines = [line.split() for line in sample.readlines()] #splitting on whitespace to create list of lists
zipped = zip(*lines)
```

See [Unpacking Argument Lists:](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

> The reverse situation occurs when the arguments are already in a list or tuple but need to be unpacked for a function call requiring separate positional arguments. For instance, the built-in range() function expects separate start and stop arguments. If they are not available separately, write the function call with the *-operator to unpack the arguments out of a list or tuple.

Comment: thank you for this. zip(*lines) only took the first letter of apple,banana.cat and egg. Also, the reason why i wanted this to e successively zipped is that i may exclude some rows inside the csv file. Thanks.

Comment: @pythonnovice Check the edit. Each line from csv is split on whitespace so it should work now.

Comment: @pythonnovice If you want to exclude some rows, you can do something like this:
lines = [line.split() for line in sample.readlines() if isGood(line)], where isGood(line) is a method that will return true if the line should be included.